# Is saving docvars for kwic dfs possible?

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

Is there a way to save docvars to kwic output dataframe? I would like to save docvars such as dates and title of documents. I've read this https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues/649 but can't understand if there was a change in the end.

I would like to later use the words surrounding my keyword to run other text analyses such as stm and tf_idf using group variables.

Comment: What do you want to do with your kiwc object?

Comment: @KoheiWatanabe thanks for the question - just added a clarification.

Comment: You should use `tokens_select(toks, pattern = "xyz*", window = 5)` to extract surrounding words. It keep all docvars and does not duplicate words (`kwic()` does).

Comment: I want to turn it later to a dfm (that I will later run a dfm_tf-idf) on. With tokens_select(), I get an error message that "dfm must have at least one non-zero value"

Comment: Please post replicable code.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this manually, see example below:

```
docvars_df <- docvars(toks.full)
docvars_df$docname <- paste("text", 1:nrow(docvars_df), sep = "")

# attaching docvars:
kwic_df <- merge(kwic_df, docvars_df, by = "docname")
```